# How can I detect the HDMI status of the Pi?

Tags: hdmi, raspbian-stretch

I'm using the command:

```
tvservice -M
```

However, is not able to detect whether HDMI is connected or not.

Is there other way to detect HDMI status?

Answer (score 3):

tvservice -M is used to monitor for changes to the HDMI status, ie. plugging or unplugging the HDMI cable.  tvservice -s will tell you the current status including whether the cable is already plugged in.  It will return a hex value, the least significant bit of which tells you the cable is plugged in (value 2) or cable is unplugged (value 1).